# Solr query in a string field's subset

Tags: solr

No body answer this question
So I ask it again

Given solr has these documents:

1. 'Danniel Wellington'
2. 'George Wellington'
3. 'Wellington'

when I search for : "Danniel Wellington"
I want to get the result as below:

1. 'Danniel Wellington'
2. 'Wellington'

Which means we want to get subset of specified string
Is there any existing analyzer which can achieve the above

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: This isn't really an analyzer issue - the analysis chain just converts input to tokens. I don't think there's any existing query mode that would allow you to do this, as the 'wellington' token would match in both cases. You might be able to hack it together by using if() and the number of terms in the field for a document.

Comment: A possible idea: Could you use a KeywordTokenizer when indexing, and a WordDelimiter to split the query into separate tokens when searching?

Comment: I am looking into the filter:
ShingleFilter : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ShingleFilterFactory
don't know if it can help me out